# Enhance the login message in QuickFIX/J

Tags: quickfixj

Maybe it's a newbie question, but is there a way to "enhance" the login message with particular tags that the acceptor side requires (such as tags 95 and 96 with specific values)?

As a reference, I'm just following [this article](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2022/02/01/build-fix-engine-using-quickfixj-and-quarkus#benefits_of_using_quarkus_with_quickfix_j) and I am getting this logon error:

```
<20231025-13:17:59, FIX.4.2:MySrcCompID->MyTgtCompID, event> (MINA session created: local=/{source-ip}:53706, class org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketSession, remote=/{target-ip}:9000)
<20231025-13:18:00, FIX.4.2:MySrcCompID->MyTgtCompID, outgoing> (8=FIX.4.29=7535=A34=149=MySrcCompID52=20231025-13:18:00.37156=MyTgtCompID98=0108=3010=249)
<20231025-13:18:00, FIX.4.2:MySrcCompID->MyTgtCompID, event> (Initiated logon request)
<20231025-13:18:00, FIX.4.2:MySrcCompID->MyTgtCompID, event> (Disconnecting: Encountered END_OF_STREAM)
```

Comment: It depends on what you want to send on these fields. It can be done via configuration https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.3.0/usage/configuration.html#:~:text=N-,Miscellaneous,-LogonTag or overriding the `Logon` message before is sent to the `Acceptor` on the `toAdmin` callback in `Application`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add fields to the Login message, you can use the `toAdmin` callaback in your quickfix.Application class.  Here is an example to add username/password fields:

```
public void toAdmin(quickfix.Message message, SessionID sessionID)
{
    final String msgType = msg.getHeader().getString(MsgType.FIELD);
    if(MsgType.LOGON.compareTo(msgType) == 0)
    {
        msg.setString(quickfix.fields.Username.FIELD, _username);
        msg.setString(quickfix.fields.Password.FIELD, _password);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grant! It works this way.

It's just that the fields are in `quickfix.field` package. And I used:

```java
msg.setInt(RawDataLength.FIELD, 32);
msg.setString(RawData.FIELD, "whatever-data-required...");
```

Comment: Alternatively, as Eduardo and Christoph mentioned as well, if you want to the fields values static enough to be in a configuration, then the easy path is to use add these in the quickfix settings file:

`LogonTag=95=32` and `LogonTag1=96=whatever-is-needed`

Answer (score 1):

**This feature is exclusive to QuickFIX/J, and is not in the C++ or C# ports.**

Starting with QuickFIX/J 2.2.0 you are able to pass `LogonTag` session settings to have these tags set on the Logon message that is sent out.

Example:

```
LogonTag=553=user
LogonTag1=554=password
```

Comment: Thanks, Christoph!

It works indeed, and thanks for showcasing a concrete example!

Comment: It should be noted that this feature is exclusive to QuickFIX/j, and **is not in the C++ or C# ports**.

Comment: @GrantBirchmeier I mean this question is for QFJ, but you are right, maybe I should make it more explicit.

Comment: @ChristophJohn 